# What does + mean in Arcanum weapon stats?

Tags: arcanum-of-steamworks-and-magick

Weapons in Arcanum are described by [two letter](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/914155-arcanum-of-steamworks-and-magick-obscura/49169753) stat values. However, the same stat is sometimes given as `number` and other times `+number`.

For example:

- Mystic gauntlets: AC +4
- Dwarven gauntlets: AC 3

Is there a difference? Is so, what is it?

Comment: My guess is no + is the base value and with + is the bonus value which could be an indication of the quality of the item in relation to its base item type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you mean **Mystic Gauntlets AC:(+4)**.
This means that this bonus stat in parentheses is an enchantment. Its effectiveness is determined by your magickal aptitude. The **Magic power available** stat below gives you what percentage of this stat you get.

Only stats in parentheses are enchantments.